# performance of calling index operator many times

Tags: c++

If we have the following code:

```
my_struct {
   string word;
   int num;
}

vector<my_struct> vec1;

//initialize vec1 to 1000 my_struct's

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

   // in the loop body, is it faster to use vec1[i].word directly, or
   //store it in a variable, like so (string temp = vec1[i].word)
   //and use the variable to refer temp to instead refer to the word?
}
```

**edit: the above is assuming that the word at the specific index of the word will have to be accessed many times within each iteration of the loop

Answer (score 7):

With: `string temp = vec1[i].word` you make a copy, so it would be slower.

Use a reference : `string& temp = vec1[i].word` instead to prevent the performance impact of a copy (I would do it if it can make further code easier to read).

Depending on what you actually do, a compiler might optimize these versions the exact same way. I would focus on writing readable code before optimal code (but still try not to make unnecessary copies).

**Edit** (bonus)

As pointed out in a comment, if you don't intent to modify the string, it is even better to write `const string& temp = vec1[i].word`. It will give the compiler and **the future reader** a hint about what you can do with your reference.

Comment: Or `my_struct& temp = vec1[i]` to store a reference to the top level object, not just with `word`; depends on what you need it for. Just make sure not to replace the value at `vec1[i]` while using the reference elsewhere unless you _want_ it to be a live view of a changing object.

Comment: Or he could just use a `const&`.

Comment: Gris, hope you are OK with that, I took your suggestion and planted it in my code. The results are good, hence here is my upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Check the experiment, which *proves* that `vec1[i].word` directly is faster than using a temporary variable:

```
linux16:/home/users/grad1459/Desktop>g++ -o foo -O3  main.cpp
linux16:/home/users/grad1459/Desktop>./foo
Without temp 1.918358000 seconds wall clock time.
With temp 2.170181000 seconds wall clock time.
```

Here is the minimal code, which **should be compiled with optimization flag(s)**:

```
int main()
{
    const int N = 10000000;
    my_struct mystruct = { "foo", 1 };
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        vec1.push_back(mystruct);

    wallclock_t t;
    double s;

    wallclock_mark(&t);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        vec1[i].word = "bla";
    s = wallclock_since(&t);
    printf("Without temp %.9f seconds wall clock time.\n", s);

    wallclock_t t1;
    double s1;

    wallclock_mark(&t1);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        string tmp = vec1[i].word;
        tmp = "bla";
    }
    s1 = wallclock_since(&t1);
    printf("With temp %.9f seconds wall clock time.\n", s1);

    return 0;
}
```

I minified the example, I have the time measurement approach in [Time measurements](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/1651-2/).

---

However, I use the [answer suggested by Gris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35073684/2411320), it's *faster with a temporary*:

```
Without temp 1.967400000 seconds wall clock time.
With temp 0.864647000 seconds wall clock time.
```

Comment: Should not be the both way same? As compiler converts both them to same three-address code to generate machine code for the task.

Comment: @MASh: Storing would involve copy constructing the value (often unavoidable if the construction could have side-effects), where referencing can access `word` by reference.

Comment: @user2357112 the code was missing, sorry! Updated. I wanted to write an intuitive answer, but then decided to experiment!

Comment: That would be **UB** @M.M.

Comment: You're timing quite different operations in your two examples. This isn't a good benchmark.

Comment: Help me make it a good one @user2357112. :) Actually I feel what you are trying to say, but I would be interested in how much the body takes to be executed, after `N` iterations. However, I am open to new suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

A good optimizing compiler may hoist the `vec1[i]` expression into a register, so it may not matter at all.

Or you could just write your code and *profile* it thus *definitively* answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

Using `vec1[i].word` is faster as you do not need to assign a value to a new location in memory, you are simply referencing an existing location instead of adding/modifying anything.

However, the performance difference is very minute.